# Want to learn spring with only core java background

Tags: spring

I am trying to learn spring and spring mvc.

All the material I checked assumed that expects me to be aware of enterprise application development or server side development.

Is there any material/book of spring for absolute novice...like me who knows only core java and not aware of any enterprise/server development.

Thanks
Vamshi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official documentation is pretty good http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-introduction. If you prefer a book i recommend "Spring in action". For Spring you don't need too much background-knowledge, but for Spring MVC it might be good to start with a basic Servlet tutorial. If you understand what Servlets are and how they work it will be easier to understand the MVC frameworks built on top of it.

I recommend you "just do it". Find a nice example (google) and follow it. In the beginning it is a bit hard to understand and might even be a tiny bit frustrating. But eventually it's worth it and you will never look back.